# browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest is not being triggered in my firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, fetch-api, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to intercept http request made using fetch / XmlHttpRequest in my firefox extension following the example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Intercept_HTTP_requests), but nothing is logged in debugger console.

```json
//manifest.json 
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    ...
    "host_permissions": [
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "permissions": ["tabs","webRequest","webRequestBlocking"]
}
```

```js
//background.js

browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener((e)=> {
    console.log(`Loading: ${e.url}`);
}, 
{urls: ["<all_urls>"], 
types: ["xmlhttprequest"]
});
```

some more details if that could help:
I am opening a new tab with local HTML page from extension directory using `browser.action.onClicked`
This page is making fetch API calls and I am trying to intercept those.

Edit 2: I updated background.js to have event listners at the top as described in migration guide to manifest v3 [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Background_scripts#convert_to_non-persistent), still no luck.

Comment: 1) See [How to open the correct devtools console to see output from an extension script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38913799) 2) ManifestV3 extensions in Firefox don't have host access immediately granted. You either need to use browser.permissions API or grant the permission using the extension icon.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for reply , I was checking right console , somebody suggested that I need to enable 'Access your data for all websites' permission in 'about:addons' page and that seem to have worked. were you suggesting the same with browser.permissions?